# porque sale este error java.lang.StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, servicio

tengo el siguiente query

```html
@NamedQuery(name = "findNivelesPersonaByCvePersona", query= "select myNivelesPersona from NivelesPersona myNivelesPersona where myNivelesPersona.persona.cveIdPersona = ?1"),
```

y lo siguiente en la clase service

```html
 public List<NivelesPersona> findByCveIdPersona(int cveIdPersona);
 
 y en la clase Impl
 
 @Override
    public List<NivelesPersona> findByCveIdPersona(int cveIdPersona) {
        return new java.util.ArrayList<NivelesPersona>(nivelesPersonaDAO.findByCveIdPersona(cveIdPersona));
    }
```

y en el DAO

```html
 public Set<NivelesPersona> findByCveIdPersona(int cveIdPersona);
 
 
 Y DAO Impl
 
 @Override
    public Set<NivelesPersona> findByCveIdPersona(int cveIdPersona) {
        return findByCveIdPersona(cveIdPersona);
    }
```

y en la clase donde lo mando a llamar

```html
person = personaService.findPersonaByPrimaryKey(1);
        cvePersona = person.getCveIdPersona();
     
       
         System.out.println("pruebaaaaaa" +nivelesPersonaService.findByCveIdPersona(cvePersona));
```

y levanta pero sale ese error
y lo marca en el DAO Impl en el return

porque?

Answer (score 2):

Cada vez que se hace una llamada a un método, se usa cierto espacio de una zona de memoria llamada `stack`. Si haces tantas llamadas a métodos que se acaba el espacio, tienes un `stack overflow`.

Habitualmente, la causa de esto es *recursión infinita*. Un método que al ejecutarse se llama a sí mismo (directamente, o mediante llamadas a otros métodos que luego llaman al método original) sin salir nunca. Mirando el `stacktrace` de la excepción, normalmente<sup>1</sup> verás de un listazo una lista enorme de llamadas a métodos que se repiten cíclicamente.

Y tú tienes:

```
@Override
public Set<NivelesPersona> findByCveIdPersona(int cveIdPersona) {
    return findByCveIdPersona(cveIdPersona);
}
```

PS: Igual tienes más fallos aparte de éste, pero como no agregas el `stacktrace` es imposible comprobar si coincide con que sea éste el método que causa el problema. Pero bueno, ahora ya sabes qué buscar.

---

<sup>1</sup>En teoría, puede ser que tengas el 99% del stack ocupado por recursión infinita de un *thread* y que justo la llamada que "causa" que no haya más memoria sea de otro método que no tiene nada que ver. Pero no he visto que pasara nunca.